# Android: Drawing a bitmap on a hardware-accelerated canvas yields corrupted display, odd behavior

Tags: android, canvas, hardware, drawbitmap

I've been stuck for several days on drawing to a hardware-accelerated canvas from a live wallpaper.

When the wallpaper launches, it's in portrait mode and everything initially looks OK: [HW canvas: upright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhmc3.png)

When I rotate the phone, the left half of the screen contains the image and the right half of the screen is black:  [HW canvas:  rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pakxy.png)

Then, when I rotate back to the original orientation, it gets weirder.  [HW canvas:  back to upright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRNQ0.png)

Drawing on a non-accelerated canvas works fine.  Just change `lockHardwareCanvas` in the code below to `lockCanvas`.  [Software canvas: upright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Un1.png) - [Software canvas: rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SREuY.png)

Sample code:

```
package reproduceproblem

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.WindowManager

class MyWallpaperService: WallpaperService() {
   override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine = WallpaperEngine()

   inner class WallpaperEngine : WallpaperService.Engine() {
      override fun onSurfaceChanged(
         holder: SurfaceHolder,
         format: Int,
         width: Int,
         height: Int
      ) {
         super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height)

         val bmp: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.webb)
         val rect = Rect( 0, 0, width, height )
         val canvas: Canvas = holder.lockHardwareCanvas()

         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, rect, null)
         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to draw on the method onSurfaceRedrawNeeded

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why this was happening, but I solved it very quickly by using libgdx.  Make sure to create a new SpriteBatch on device rotation, because SpriteBatch internally sets its own width and height, and it doesn't update once created.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).